# Nginx+Php-Fpm - FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown"

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi

Доброе время суток. Добрался до настройки Nginx с FastCGI на Fedora 24, но Nginx пишет

> 2016/12/21 08:12:51 [error] 3427#0: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: yaboku.ru.local, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "yaboku.ru.local"

Гуглю второй час, все бесполезно, пути верные

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name yaboku.ru.local;
access_log /var/log/nginx/yaboku-nginx-access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/yaboku-nginx-error.log;

root /home/zaars/Project/Yii2/yaboku.ru/web;

location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_$
}
}
```

Не знаю уже, в чем проблема....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Спасибо, нашел решение сам. Проблема была в в конфиге php-fpm: поменял пользователя с дефолтного apache на тот, под которым запускается сервер, и все заработало.

Спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так

```
set $yii_bootstrap "index.php";

location / {
    index  index.html $yii_bootstrap;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$yii_bootstrap?$args;
}

location ~ \.php {

    fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

    set $fsn /$yii_bootstrap;
    if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
        set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
    }

    fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
            return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Увы, этот вариант не изменил результат работы (

Comment: Это очень странно, у меня работает именно этот конфиг. Возможно, проблема в настройках fpm. Попробуйте через unix-socket связать